# customtkinter создание нового окна

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Как в библиотеке customtkinter создавать новое окно по нажатию на кнопку

```
class App(CTk.CTk):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.title("Pass manager")

        self.button_frame = CTk.CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color="#343a40",border_width=0,corner_radius=0)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.button_addNewPass = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Add New Password",width=200,command=self.addPass)
        self.button_addNewPass.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(5),pady=(5))

        self.button_Settings = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Settings",width=200,)
        self.button_Settings.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(5),pady=(5))
    
    def addPass(asdasd):
        #при выполнении открывается ещё одно окно желательно чтоб можно было настраиветь как и этот класс
        pass
```

я сделал так но не работает настройка окна.

```
class Pass(CTk.CTk):
    def __init__(self,parent) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.title("Pass manager")

    class App(CTk.CTk):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.title("Pass manager")

        self.button_frame = CTk.CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color="#343a40",border_width=0,corner_radius=0)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.button_addNewPass = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Add New Password",width=200,command=self.addPass)
        self.button_addNewPass.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(5),pady=(5))

        self.button_Settings = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Settings",width=200,)
        self.button_Settings.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(5),pady=(5))
    
    def addPass(self):
        win =  Pass(self)
        win.mainloop()
```

вышло так только настраивать окно никак не получается(
[image: какая фигня вышла]

Comment: точно также, только класс Frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось как то так:

```
class Pass(CTk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("430x200")
        self.title("Add Password")
        self.resizable(False,False)
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("430x260")
        self.title("Pass manager")
        self.resizable(False,False)

        self.button_frame = CTk.CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color="#343a40",border_width=0,corner_radius=0)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew",padx=(5,5),pady=(5,5))

        self.button_addNewPass = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Add New Password",width=200,command=self.addPass)
        self.button_addNewPass.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(5),pady=(5))

        self.button_Settings = CTk.CTkButton(master=self.button_frame,text="Settings",width=200,)
        self.button_Settings.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(5),pady=(5))

        self.pass_list = CTk.CTkFrame(master=self,fg_color="#343a40")
        self.pass_list.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nsew",padx=(5,5),pady=(5,5))
    
    def addPass(self):
        new = Pass()
        new.mainloop()
```